# Halcon hand-eye calibration error is very large

Tags: halcon

I am trying to use Halcon to calibrate the hand and eye on the UR10. The robot pose type is zyx/abg. After calibration, it shows Inconsistent pose pairs and then produces a large error. Sometimes it will show 'Only few tilted robot poses available, which might result in a reduced accuracy of the calibration results.  'UR10 robot pose directly from the robot read above, pose should be no problem, there is no one can help me, thank you very much.

Attempts have been made to modify the pose type and to manually input the pose from the robot's operator panel